# Thousands of cAdvisor Docker containers created until disk runs out of space

Tags: linux, docker, google-compute-engine, cadvisor

Google Compute Engine container-optimized VM image has a built-in cAdvisor container that gets started automatically.

In the last three days, an infinite loop started to create ~15000 containers of the cAdvisor image until the disk ran out of space.

The versions are:

> Linux docker-04 3.16-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.3-2~bpo70+1 (2014-09-21) x86_64
>
> Docker version 1.2.0, build fa7b24f

How can this bug be fixed?

For a temporary fix, I've deleted all ~15000 containers using the following script:

> docker ps -a | grep 'days ago' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the latest cAdvisor release (0.7.0). It has been fixed since and a patch release was made (0.7.1). GCE container image should pick it up and release a new build soon.

If you see any issues, please report them via the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/google/cadvisor).

Comment: When will 0.7.1 be released?

Comment: It was released some time back. We are now at version 0.8.0